# Facebook graph API: Upload page image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to upload an image to a facebook page as the page picture (not a photo album picture) through the graph api? And then is it possible to also define the offsets to create the miniature picture when a user writes posts as this page?

Comment: Are you talking about this http://pokit.org/get/8fe9ff172365e36ad77bc344c01ae4c1.png ?

Comment: With "page picture" I mean the picture at the left of a facebook page: Below the facebook logo. And with "miniature picture" I mean something like the smaller image at your screenshot: That one in upper left corner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes below worked for me in many places

```
$file = '@' . realpath('path_to_image');

// Fill in your arguments.
$args = array(  
  'access_token' => $token,  
  'image' => $file,
  'aid' => $albumid
);  

// Send the api request.
$data = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Comment: That uploads a photo to the pages album, right? That's not what I am looking for.

Comment: @stofl I think Facebook does not allow to change a page settings through graph api